# What is a good chart (if needed at all) to visualize a best and worst case scenario using excel

Tags: excel, charts, data-visualization

I'm looking at multiple segments of a business YOY customer loss (see below)

```
         No Of Customers Lost
Segment    Best Case    Worst Case
   A          1500          3000
   B          450           600
```

What is a good way to visualize this best case, worst case range

Comment: Well if in segment A each customer only spends $10 but in segment B each one spends a $1000 then which has the largest consequence...

Comment: How big are the segments before measuring loss? I assume they are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, a chart called "Clustered Column" makes this kind of data pop out nicely:

[image]

Make your spreadsheet like this & highlight it:

[image]

Then click Insert, then Charts, & pick this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Open High Low Close (OHLC) chart as below, i recomend that because you are showing a range, and this chart is best to show ranges

[image]